# System.arraycopy() throwing out-of-bounds exception

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, indexoutofboundsexception

I created a generic resizing circular buffer based on arrays, which was doing well in my tests untill this particular case when

1. head == tail and
2. total array is filled with elements

I expected the array to resize as usual , put head = 0 , tail = new position to insert , and all to be well. But this is what i'm getting as output :

```
adding : e
head : 5 tail : 5 , size : 12
a b c d e f g h i j k l 

adding : f
resizing array to size: 24
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at ResizingCircularArray.resize(ResizingCircularArray.java:16)
    at ResizingCircularArray.enqueue(ResizingCircularArray.java:33)
    at ResizingCircularArray.main(ResizingCircularArray.java:105)
```

Probably something minute yet significant , but i cant seem to locate what that might be. Can someone help out ?

**Note** :
head > position from where next dequeue will take place
tail > position into where next enqueue will take place

**Edit:** following ns47731's suggestion , i changed my arraycopy line from`system.arraycopy(arr, head, tempArr, 0, size);` to`System.arraycopy(arr, 0, tempArr, 0, size);`. This , Though solves the exception problem , induces error in logic , which is apparent below :

```
43.dequeing : f
head : 13 tail : 20 , size : 7
null null null null null null null null null null null null null g h i j k l m null null null null 

44.dequeing : g
resizing array to size: 12
head : 0 tail : 6 , size : 6
null null null null null null null null null null null null
```

ie, data part `g h i j k l m` are getting dropped.

I realised that the problem was with System.arraycopy() itself , its designed for linear arrays , not circular one , so i created a simple version of it for myself , that would work with circular arrays :

```
private void arrayCopy(E[] srcArr , int srcpos , E[] destArr , int destpos , int length){
        for(int index = 0 ; index < length ; index++){
            destArr[index] = srcArr[head++];
            if(head == srcArr.length){
                head = (head % srcArr.length);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'll have to add exception-cases later , but this , in general works.

**Modified Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class ResizingCircularArray<E> {

    private int head = 0;
    private int tail = 0;
    private int size = 0; // a measure of non-null elements in the array
    private E[] arr;

    // Modified version of System.arraycopy() to work with circular array.
    private void arrayCopy(E[] srcArr , int srcpos , E[] destArr , int destpos , int length){
        for(int index = 0 ; index < length ; index++){
            destArr[index] = srcArr[head++];
            if(head == srcArr.length){
                head = (head % srcArr.length);
            }
        }
    }

    private void resize() {
        System.out.println("resizing array to size: " + 2 * size);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E[] tempArr = (E[]) new Object[2 * size];
        arrayCopy(arr, head, tempArr, 0, size);
        head = 0;
        tail = size; // tail point to where the NEXT element will land
        arr = tempArr;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ResizingCircularArray() {
        arr = (E[]) new Object[3];

    }

    public void enqueue(E item) {
        if (item == null)
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    " adding null values is not allowed ");
        if (size == arr.length) {
            resize();
        }
        if (tail == arr.length) {
            // going round
            tail = (tail % arr.length);
        }
        arr[tail++] = item;
        size++;
        System.out.println("head : " + head + " tail : " + tail + " , size : "
                + size);
    }

    public E dequeue() {
        if (!(size > 0))
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("size is negative");
        E item = arr[head];
        arr[head++] = null;
        if (head == (arr.length)) {
            head = (head % arr.length); // =0
        }
        --size;
        if (size == arr.length / 4) {
            resize();
        }
        System.out.println("head : " + head + " tail : " + tail + " , size : "
                + size);
        return item;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public E sample(int offset) {
        if (offset < 0)
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
                    "provided offset is out of bounds");
        return arr[head + offset];
        /*
         * NOTE : the check for (head+offset)>tail as pointed out by sos will
         * work in case of linear array , Not in case of Circular array because
         * when tail comes around in a circle , tail will be < than head and the
         * above check will create trouble
         */
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void display() {
        for (E item : arr)
            System.out.print(item + " ");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ResizingCircularArray<String> r = new ResizingCircularArray<String>();
        String line = null;
        String[] segment, parsed;
        boolean endFlag = false;
        int count = 0;

        try (BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "CircArrayPoints.txt"))) {
            line = is.readLine();
            segment = line.trim().split(";");
            System.out.println("total commands : " + segment.length);
            for (int i = 0; !segment[i].equals("stop") && !endFlag; i++) {
                parsed = segment[i].split(" ");
                count++;
                switch (parsed[0]) {
                case "enq":
                    System.out.println(count+ ".adding : " + parsed[1]);
                    r.enqueue(parsed[1]);
                    r.display();
                    break;
                case "deq":
                    if (r.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Empty queue");
                        endFlag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    // print after checking isEmpty() to make sure
                    // sample(0) doesn't call null etc
                    System.out.println(count+ ".dequeing : " + r.sample(0));
                    r.dequeue();
                    r.display();
                    break;
                case "disp":
                    r.display();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Files : CircArrayPoints.txt**

```
enq a;enq b;enq c;enq d;enq e;enq f;enq g;enq h;enq i;enq j;enq k;enq l;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;enq a;enq b;enq c;enq d;enq e;enq f;enq g;enq h;enq i;enq j;enq k;enq l;enq m;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;disp;stop
```

Comment: `        if (tail == arr.length) {
            // going round
            tail = (tail % arr.length);
        }` This is kind of useless. If you're going to physically check equality, then you can just say `tail=0`. If you use `tail=tail%arr.length` then you don't need to if statement at all, when tail is less than arr.length, then tail won't change.

Comment: You are right. I kept it to tell myself what i was doing. if that makes sense. I'll remove that once the final test is done.

Answer (score 1):

Make your array copy read

```
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, tempArr, 0, size);
```

Why? argument #2 (int) startPos is where it should start copying from the source array, you were starting at the length of the array causing an index out of bounds.

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object%2C%20int%2C%20java.lang.Object%2C%20int%2C%20int) for more details on that method.

**Edit**: First of all I solved your inital problem and you should figure out the rest of this on your own.. Read the arraycopy javadoc (that is very well written by the way). it should be System.arraycopy(arr, head, tempArr, 0, tail-head);

Comment: @SomjitNag I copied your code and text file and ran it, it worked fine for me.

Comment: I edited my previous comment , because While your answer solves the exception that was being thrown , it creates a different problem. I'm updating my post to reflect it.

Comment: I figured that System.arraycopy doesn't work for circular arrays , so created a version for myself that works with them. I'v updated my post and code accordingly. ps: i'll haveto add the exceptions parts to my version of arrayCopy() later on.

Comment: did you try changing it to System.arraycopy(arr, head, tempArr, 0, tail-head);

Comment: What would be the benefit in that ? `tail - head` doesn't seem like a fool proof way of getting the size of the circular array. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Well I tested it and it works fine with that change, I dont understand what your talking about when you say arraycopy doesnt work with a circular array, a circular array is something you build in code. Primitive arrays are and cannot be "circular" by default you have to implement it like you are doing. So saying array copy doesn't work for circular arrays isn't logical.

Comment: when you do `tail-head` : when tail > head , it gives a certain size , now , after tail has moved past the last entry in the array , and it has to come back to one of the positions initially occupied by Head , `tail-head` will give a negative value. That is why i havent used it.